# MS Access Data-Definition Query Add Referential Integrity Constraint

Tags: ms-access, foreign-keys, constraints, referential-integrity

I am trying to write a data-definition query to add a constraint to a table that enforces referential integrity

```
ALTER TABLE SS_SIZE ALTER COLUMN NDS TEXT 
CONSTRAINT fk_NDS REFERENCES NDS (NDS) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
```

I've also tried

```
ALTER TABLE SS_SIZE ALTER COLUMN NDS 
CONSTRAINT fk_NDS_NDS FOREIGN KEY (NDS) REFERENCES NDS ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
```

Neither of these will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
ALTER TABLE SS_SIZE 
    ADD CONSTRAINT fk_NDS FOREIGN KEY (NDS) 
        REFERENCES NDS (NDS) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
```

Please note, that DAO doesn't support `ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE` options, you should use ADO for this. Query designer uses DAO, so you won't be able to execute the query with cascade options using query designer.

VBA ADO example:

```
CurrentProject.Connection.Execute strSQL
```